# How can I sort an array of a structure?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, sorting

I have an array of a structure. 
It's declared like this

```
Public SongsList as New List(Of Song)
```

"Song" it's structure's name. 
It has 2 variables : path and name; 
I'm wondering how I can sort this array by the name.

```
Public Structure Song
  Public Path as String
  Public Name as String
End Structure
```

I tried this

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
Dim sorted = SongsList.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Name).ToList 
Dim i As Integer 
For i = 0 To sorted.Count - 1
    ListBox1.Items.Add(sorted(i).Name.ToString) 
Next
```

But it throws a `NullReferenceException`.

This is how I'm adding items to SongsList

```
Dim open As New OpenFileDialog
open.Title = "Add songs"
open.Filter = "MP3 Files(*.mp3)|*.mp3"
open.Multiselect = True
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
If open.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    For Each SelectedSong As String In open.FileNames
        i += 1
        Dim songToAdd As New Song
        songToAdd.Path = SelectedSong.ToString
        songToAdd.Name = GetSafeFileName(SelectedSong.ToString)
        SongsList.Add(songToAdd)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(SongsList(i).Path)
    Next
End If
```

Comment: I edited your question to include the code you mentioned in the comments of OneFineDay's answer; but please next time try to include the code you have tried - even if it didn't work. Now, can you tell us how do you fill `SongsList`?

Comment: Why do you call `.ToString` on variables which are already strings?

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Lambda expression. It uses the field you select in the `OrderBy` function. Lets Override the `ToString` method to tell the Listbox what to display, then you can just set the list as the datasource.

The class:

```
Public Class Song
  Public Property Path as String
  Public Property Name as String
  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return Me.Path
  End If
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim open As New OpenFileDialog
open.Title = "Add songs"
open.Filter = "MP3 Files(*.mp3)|*.mp3"
open.Multiselect = True
If open.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
  For Each SelectedSong As String In open.FileNames
    Dim songToAdd As New Song
    songToAdd.Path = SelectedSong
    songToAdd.Name = GetSafeFileName(SelectedSong.ToString)
    SongsList.Add(songToAdd)
   Next
End If
Listbox1.DataSource = SongsList.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Name).ToList
```

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work. 
Here is the code : 
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        Dim sorted = SongsList.OrderBy(Function(s) s.SongName).ToList
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To sorted.Count - 1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(sorted(i).SongName.ToString)
        Next

Comment: NullReferenceException

Comment: You wrote above that it was `Name` in the structure and not `SongName`. Which one is it?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I've rewritted the code and I forgot about it. I'm sorry. Use "Name".

Comment: Yes. The list it's cleared everytime I run the program.

Comment: Where do you get that exception? Also `SelectedSong` is a `String` so no use calling `.ToString` on it.

Answer (score 0):

*Very similar to OneFineDay's answer...

You don't need a custom class, just use a `List(Of FileInfo)`:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim open As New OpenFileDialog
    open.Title = "Add songs"
    open.Filter = "MP3 Files(*.mp3)|*.mp3"
    open.Multiselect = True
    If open.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim songs As New List(Of FileInfo)
        For Each SelectedSong As String In open.FileNames
            songs.Add(New FileInfo(SelectedSong))
        Next
        songs = songs.OrderBy(Function(fi) fi.Name).ToList
        ListBox1.DataSource = songs
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "FullName"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim fi As FileInfo = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, FileInfo)
        Dim name As String = fi.Name
        Dim fullPath As String = fi.FullName
        Debug.Print("name = " & name)
        Debug.Print("fullPath = " & fullPath)
    End If
End Sub
```